# Generate unique serial numbers for mass produced products

Tags: c#, python, uniqueidentifier, unique-key

I need help with understanding how to tackle this problem of generating Unique Serial Numbers or UIDs for mass produced products.

I will be producing products in mass, as of now I think that I will be making >50000 units. When these units are manufactured and ready I must test them before dispatching and at which point in time I would also like to give each one of them a Unique ID.

I was thinking of writing an application to generate a *128 bit unique number generator application* and ask the testers to run it on their jigs, generate an ID, assign the ID and then carry out testing.

But my question is, please look at the illustration below, if my same application is running on say 3 (or more) different jigs **in parallel at the same time**, how do I make sure that the numbers generated by these systems are **never ever** equal to one another?

How do I programmatically make sure that **Unique Serial #1 != Unique Serial #2 != Unique Serial #3**?

If they are ever equal by any chance I will land in great trouble tracking them, once they are out.

There are some hardware approaches, such as making use of UID chips/EEPROMs from Atmel or Maxim, but they will add cost. I wish to solve this at software level and keep the hardware approach as a last resort.

I have found out that the test jigs are capable of running **C#** or **Python** applications.

Please help!

[image: Illustration of Unique Serial # Generator application running on three different test jigs.]

Comment: Idea A: Have the program on each machine insert UIDs into a global UID database, and check against that database when generating new ones?

Comment: whatever formula you use make sure you allow enough unique id's in each batch for the three jigs, if you start further production do the same again

Comment: Idea B: Prepend/append each generated UID with the generator machine's own unique serial number?

Comment: twitter has solved this problem for their purposes: https://github.com/twitter/snowflake

Comment: Idea C: Assign each machine a separate UID batch range.

Comment: Are there any other specific requirements around these serial numbers.. for example, must have properties like maintain order in which they are generated and assigned.. Does GUIDs already suggested in answer below fit your needs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is a GUID generator.  GUIDs composed of network ID and time are considered unique.  The potential for duplication is insignificant.

Comment: C# has a built in `Guid` class. You can call 'Guid.NewGuid()' to get a random Guid. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I was in a similar situation and [solved it](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/607329/Thread-safety-with-SQL-Server) with the help of centralized "generator", a stored procedure in SQL.

Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UniqueKeys](
    [Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [App] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [System] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [Key] [bigint] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Here is the code for the SP:

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetUniqueKeyTV]
        @app VARCHAR(100) ,
        @sys VARCHAR(100) ,
        @retVal BIGINT OUT
    AS 
        BEGIN
            DECLARE @T TABLE([Key] BIGINT);
            SET NOCOUNT ON

            MERGE INTO dbo.UniqueKeys WITH (TABLOCK) AS Target
                USING ( VALUES
                    ( @app ,
                      @sys ,
                      1
                    ) ) AS Source ( [App], [System], [Key] )
                ON ( Target.App = Source.App
                     AND Target.[System] = Source.[System]
                   )
                WHEN MATCHED 
                    THEN UPDATE
                        SET     Target.[Key] = Target.[Key] + 1 
                WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET 
                    THEN 
           INSERT  (
                  [App] ,
                  [System] ,
                  [Key]

                ) VALUES
                ( Source.[App] ,
                  Source.[System] ,
                  Source.[Key]

                ) OUTPUT 
                   inserted.[Key] INTO @T;
            SELECT  @retVal = [Key]
            FROM    @T

            SET NOCOUNT OFF
        END

    GO
```

It lets you create sequential numbers for an application and system, but you can modify it to suit a specific need.